# material ui Installation configure

Tags: material-design, material-ui

USER MATERIAL ui

1.jsx

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton;

var MyAwesomeReactComponent = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <RaisedButton label="Default" />
    );
  }

});

module.exports = MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

browserify 1.jsx -o 1.js

```
Error: Parsing file C:\Users\wzx\AppData\Roaming\npm\1.jsx: Unexpected token (7:
11)
    at Deps.parseDeps
```

unknow  `<RaisedButton label="Default" />`

github :https://github.com/callemall/material-ui

1    `npm install material-ui`

2  `Then how to do?`

3 `...`

4`....`

i what should i do next?

i need help, i have done a few days

Answer (score 1):

I got confused as well, but I worked it out after I searched around.

```
$ sudo npm install -g browserify
$ npm install --save-dev reactify
```

you now have all the dependencies, next you need the file, your example is:

```
var React = require('react'),
  mui = require('material-ui'),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton;

var MyAwesomeReactComponent = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <RaisedButton label="Default" />
    );
  }

});

module.exports = MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

you then need run this command

```
$ browserify -t reactify <path to jsx file> -o <path to output location, including file name>
```

this will output the file, which will have everything you need!